# Diameter of directed Erdős–Rényi graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G_{N, p} = (V, E)$ be a directed Erdős–Rényi graph. More specifically, $G_{N, p}$ is such that $|V| = N$ and, for all $i, j \neq i \in V$, the probability that $(i, j) \in E$ is $p$.

In [this paper](http://euclid.trentu.ca/aejm/V3N1/Pike.V3N1.pdf), Theorem 5 proves that $G_{N, p}$ is strongly connected with high probability as long as (somewhat unsurprisingly) $p > \log N / N$.

Now, I am wondering if any result exists on the *diameter* of $G_{N, p}$. Given the similarity between the connectivity thresholds of directed and undirected Erdős–Rényi graphs, one could think that diameters should be similar, too. However, I did not find any result about the topic.